# What does Angular install command really do?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I can understand that after executing install command, Angular will be installed in our machine. But I could not find the angular files under ProgramFiles folder after executing the below command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

When we install VisualStudio we can find related files under Program Files folder as given below.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0
```

Can someone help me to understand how this angular command works and angular file locations.

Answer (score 2):

npm is installation of a node package... not an application (hence not in Program Files)...

Installing it local (without -g), means the module will be available only for a project you installed it in (the directory you were in, when ran npm install).

Global install, instead puts the module into your Node.js path (OS dependent), and will be accessible from any project, without the need to install it separately for each.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the OP, I'm assuming that you're on Windows.

Since it is installed in Global Mode as you used `-g` it should be present in your

`C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\roaming\npm\`

There should be an `ng` file present there. And all your node_modules would be stored in the node_modules folder right there inside the npm folder.

Answer (score 1):

This command doesn't install angular as a tool in the system but it is a package which can be used to develop an application.

Since you ran `npm install -g @angular/cli`. It will install this package globally where you don't have to install it again. It will be available globally at command line.

whenever you run `npm install` with `-g` which is a flag for `--global` will be installed at your node home. The path will be `%appdata%/roaming/npm` in this folder you can see a folder named `node_modules` which holds all the global packages including some `.bat` files like the one you installed `ng`.

`@angular/cli` provides some commands which can be run using `cmd`, since it is installed globally *(which is recommended)* can be used on the `terminal/command` prompt using `ng` cmdlet function like for creating a new angular application `ng new MyNgApp`.

You can understand one more thing is that if your application has a dependency on a package then add them using `--save/-S` in the dependency block in the `package.json` and `--save-dev/-D` for development dependency for `dev-dependency`.