# Angular CLI update on Windows 11 not working

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install, windows-11

I wanted to update the Angular CLI globally on my Windows 11 system.
Using `ng version` I get the info, that version 9.1.0 is the current CLI version:

[image]

I tried then

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But the version is still 9.1.0

I tried to delete all data in: AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules and then

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

But its still 9.1.0

Even after delete all node_modules files and do

```
npm cache clean --force
```

the ng version command still shows 9.1.0 as CLI version - even if angular is nowhere installed. Is there a hidden (old) installation that cannot be updated? But every `npm install -g` command recreates the deleted node_modules files, thus this should be the right location.

Comment: Try `where ng`. This should show the directory from where `ng` is begin executed.

Comment: And if I have 2 location like C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng and AppData\Roaming\npm\ng ... which one is taken? Or delete both?

Comment: When you try to execute `ng`, the first one is taken. no need to check the second one.

Comment: You can check both versions by specifying the complete path, like doing: `"C:\Program Files\nodejs\ng" version`  and/or  `AppData\Roaming\npm\ng version`

Comment: Thanks. After deleting all, I see that @angular-Folder are NOT installed in "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules" but instead in the AppData folder - even if I run the command line as admin - shouldn't a global installed AngularCLI not be installed unter nodejs in ProgramFiles in Windows?

Comment: *globally* means that ng is used by all your projects (see: [Why npm install -g @angular/cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48828865/why-npm-install-g-angular-cli) )

Comment: [What does Angular install command really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53928482/what-does-angular-install-command-really-do)

Comment: But I thought, global modules are installed in "Program Files" ... as I now get the error for ng version: 
 Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng'

Thus. install -g installs AngularCLI in AppData - but ng --version expect it in ProgramFiles